# Fail on purchasing in via Windows store

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to purchase item via win store.
It is always worked, until today.

In this place:

```
receiptString = await CurrentApp.GetProductReceiptAsync( product.ProductId );
```

I got this: "Internal server error" (500).

And this:
An unknown error has occurred on our side. Wait for a while and then try again. Error code: 0x801901f4

But money is withdrawn from the card

Comment: This community is for English questions/answers. Adding images with russian text is of no help

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto translated

Comment: I think this was an issue for few hours with Microsoft Purchase API's. I just tested In App Purchase and works fine.